# Metal roof over mold, lichens, moss

Tags: roof, mold, shingles

I want to install a metal roof over my single layer shingle one on my unheated garage. It has mold and MOSS and lichens. Can I put a metal roof over mold and moss and lichens?

Comment: Does not the old roof hold water any longer? Othewise, what is your purpose? Are the moss and lichens on the top or bottom side of your old roof? What are your shingles made of? Is any kind of ventilation provided for the underside of your current roof? I believe this infomation is required to propose an good answer rather than merely to guess.

Comment: It would depend on how much moisture is held by the remaining materials . Moisture will promote corrosion of steel . It will depend in part on how the underside of the steel is protected ( bare, galvanized, coated ?). As commented; the type of ventilation will be important.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be no you cannot. It may depend on your location, maybe not, but a metal roof will allow condensation to form on the underside and that will allow other things to grow like mildew, from the existing growth you have, or keep the other alive too. You will need to clear the old roofing material and lay a condensation barrier down to keep the condensation from the metal from damaging the under structure of the roof.